# NSInteger always zero

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, int, nsinteger

I have a NSInteger which always returns zero :( I have it declared like:

```
NSInteger level;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger level;
```

The synthetize:

```
@synthesize fileName, filePath, theActualIndexPath, titleBar, level;
```

Then when using `NSLog(@"%d", level)` always returns 0, even after

```
level++;
```

Or

```
level += 1;
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm 100% sure of adding 1 to `level` but can't understand what's wrong :(

### EDIT:

The if statement where I use this NSInteger

```
if (level == 0) {
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Test";

} else {
    self.navigationItem.title = self.titleBar;

}
```

That always ends on the first, even after adding 1

Comment: Did you check your RAM for corruption? Otherwise, this cannot happen when all info you gave us is right.

Comment: hmm I doubt it's being corrupted, as OS X and all apps seems to work fine. The only time I use 0 is on a if statement and on NSLog, and ofcourse when trying to sum one, but that's what's not working :(

Comment: Show the `@synthesize statement` and the rest of the method surrounding setting and displaying level.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in that lines of code. Have you tried changing the compiler (from gcc to llvm or the other way around)? clean and build? build and analyze?

Comment: I think the problem is that I try to use a multi level navigation controller. For this I alloc the same view controller again, and I think the level integer is being reallocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you declaring `level` twice?

Remove this line: `NSInteger level;`

The first declaration of `level` is a globally scoped variable, the second an instance variable of the class. Depending on your scope, the `level` being incremented by `++level` is different from the `level` being printed by `NSLog("%d", level);` and tested by `if (level == 0)`.

**EDIT**

Yes. Why would you expect `level` to not be newly allocated if you alloc another instance of the view controller? If you want to do that then you've either got to make the variable `static`, which shares it among instances of the same class, or make sure you do something like this:

```
MyViewController *newViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init]; // However this goes
newViewController.level = oldViewController.level; // Make sure you pass the level on
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I try to use a multi level navigation controller. For this I alloc the same view controller again, and I think the `level` integer is being reallocated

Answer (score 1):

The variable that being changed is not the same variable being accessed (in the `if` statement).

In the console print the values and addresses of `level` both where it is being set (before and after) and where s is being accessed (in the `if` statement.

Comment: I think the problem is that I try to use a multi level navigation controller. For this I alloc the same view controller again, and I think the level integer is being reallocated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
in the .h

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger level; // not an object assign not needed
```

in the .m

```
@synthesize level = _level;  
self.level = self.level + 1;  // and try this
```

And remove the line

```
NSInteger level;
```

Is this working?

Comment: There a side effect to removing the declaration `NSInteger level;`, the value of level (or in the recommendation _level) will not be available in the debugger.

Comment: Still not working, even changed the variable name to folderLevel, it still doesn't adds one :/

Comment: why is 'folderLevel' a red flag?

Comment: folderLevel is meant to be a integer to track the level of the folder hierarchy my app has

Comment: @zad0xsis you need to post more code than that, because there is a lot that can go wrong and your little piece of code is not showing that. And with my code you ABSOLUTLY need to use `self` if you are testing directly for `level` without the `self` it won't work. And rule of tum, you should always use self.aProperty instead of bypassing your accessor all the time. (excpt in a custom accessor where you need direct acces)